# Excel file to TEMP SQL Server Database Table w/ unknown columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

I have an Excel file that has 4 known column headers and the rest will be Year/Month.  The Year/Month column headers can be different in every file.  There could be any number of these Y/M columns.  In my WinForms application, the user will select an Excel file.  What I need to figure out how to do is to take that Excel file, import it to a temporary table in my database, do some things, then delete the temp table.  Everything I have seen is where you know what the columns will be ahead of time.

How can I accomplish this?  Is it even possible?

I will try to be more clear.  I have an excel file.  The number of and names of the columns will vary(so I cant just create a temp table since I dont know what the fields are).  I am taking that excel file and putting it into a local datatable in my application.  I need to create a table on my sql database that mirrors that local database then copy the data there.  So from my application how do I create a temp table on the mssql server.

Comment: Did you try using * instead of column names?

Comment: there is no temp table yet.  I need to create that table at runtime using the excel file.

Comment: What do you mean there is no temp table yet? Who said there were? Simply query the data from excel sheet(s), based on that data create temp table and load with SqlBulkCopy. I wonder why you do that with MS SQL server table that you would drop afterwards. You could instead say use an SQLite in memory database (or LiteDB ...).

Comment: Also, if enabled, you could directly query an excel table from within SQL Server. OpenRowSource as I remember but has been long I didn't use,

Comment: So, you've got a few questions here.  really need to update update your question with exactly what part of this you're struggling with.  There are plenty of examples of reading excel files via .net, I would recommend looking at 3rd party libraries rather than Office Interops though (EPPlus, OpenXML for example) that will deal with your variable column names easier

Comment: BTW, I didn't mean office interops but direct reading via ADO.Net.

Comment: While testing to see if what I wanted to do would work, i manually imported an excel file into my sql database using the wizard.  I then created stored procedures that would look at those tables, being sure not to call out any unknown fields, just using select *.  The results of the procedure are using in my application.  So now that I have everything working with the manually imported tables, I need to figure out how to do it from my application where the user selects an excel file in the application.

Comment: What is different? It is again select *, no? Looks like you real problem is that you are using wizards instead of code.

Comment: The question is how do i take the excel file the user selects on their computer in the application and put it into a temp table in excel?  I have seen where you need to move the file onto the server, then use like openrowset or something like that.

Comment: I used the wizard the first time to put my data into a table so i could test if my stored procedures that manipulated that data would work.  Now that I know it works, I need to, not use wizards, and figure out how to go from an excel file on a users computer and import it to a temp ms sql table.

Comment: Sorry now it turned out to be a temp table in Excel and I don't know what is a temp table in excel.  If you meant SQL server, then I repeat, at client you simply query the excel table(s) into datatables and also GetOleDbSchemaTable to create your SQL table, then upload with SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: Lets put it this way, there are no tables in my database.  In my winforms application a user selects an excel file.  I need the program to take that excel file and put it into my database where the stored procedures can be run on them.  Does that make more sense?  Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: Just to reiterate, your question needs to focus on a specific question.  Maybe you should rephrase this to say for example, "How do I import an Excel file with variable fields".  Forget about all the rest of this for now and break your problem into manageable chunks

Comment: @CetinBasoz I think you get it.  How do I do those things?  Well i know how to create datatables and load them with data from the excel file.  I think the GetOleDBSchemaTable is where I am lost.  I know sqlbulkcopy.  How do I create that temp table to be able to use sqlbulkcopy?

Comment: It sounds like what you should *really* be doing is unpivoting your data before inserting it into SQL. That way you have rows instead of columns

Comment: @Charlieface how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

(Comments are getting rather messy. Here is one of my routines where I get tables from excel file - C# sorry):

```
private List<System.Data.DataTable> GetTablesFromExcel(string dataSource)
{
  List<System.Data.DataTable> tables = new List<System.Data.DataTable>();
  using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"+
  string.Format("Data Source={0};",dataSource)+
  "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\""))
  {
  con.Open();
  var schemaTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,null);
  foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
  {
    string sheetName = (string)row["TABLE_NAME"];
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("Select * from [{0}]",sheetName), con);
    System.Data.DataTable t = new System.Data.DataTable(sheetName);
    t.Load( cmd.ExecuteReader() );
    tables.Add( t );
  }
  con.Close();
  }
  return tables;
}
```

EDIT: And this is SqlBulkCopy sample (sorry also comments are in Turkish but you could see temp table creation is done with string thus you could build at runtime with StringBuilder):

```
static readonly string sqlConnectionString = @"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;";
static readonly string path = @"d:\temp\dersler.xlsx"; // excel dosyasi
static readonly string sheetName = "Dersler$";

void Main()
{
    using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(
          "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path +
          ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes\""))
    using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        // Excelden veriyi al ve SqlBulkCopy ile servera yaz  
        // Kaynak
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("select * from [{0}]", sheetName), cn);


        SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(scn);
        // Mapping  
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "[SiraNo]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "[DersinAdi]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "[SinifTuru]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "[SinifSeviyesi]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(4, "[DersTuru]");
        sbc.ColumnMappings.Add(5, "[Secmeli]");

        cn.Open();
        scn.Open();

        SqlCommand createTemp = new SqlCommand();
        createTemp.CommandText = @"if exists
   (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.objects 
   WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[tempdb]..[##Dersler]','U'))
   BEGIN
        drop table [##Dersler];
   END
   
  create table ##Dersler 
  (
        [SiraNo] int primary key not null,
        [DersinAdi] nvarchar(250) not null,
        [SinifTuru] nvarchar(50) null,
        [SinifSeviyesi] int,
        [DersTuru] nvarchar(50),
        [Secmeli] bit
  )
  ";
        createTemp.Connection = scn;
        createTemp.ExecuteNonQuery();

        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        // SqlBulkCopy'nin propertyleri
        sbc.DestinationTableName = "##Dersler";
        sbc.NotifyAfter = 20; // 10000 alti kullanilmaz da sizin dataniz cok az
        sbc.BatchSize = 10;
        sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 300; // Saniye. 5 dk cok bile fazla
        sbc.EnableStreaming = true;

        sbc.SqlRowsCopied += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-- Copied {0} rows to {1}.",
            e.RowsCopied,
            ((SqlBulkCopy)sender).DestinationTableName);
        };

        sbc.WriteToServer(rdr);

        if (!rdr.IsClosed) { rdr.Close(); }

        cn.Close();
        
        DataTable t = new DataTable(); // Yazdigimiza bakalim
        t.Load(new SqlCommand("select * from ##Dersler", scn).ExecuteReader());
        
        scn.Close();

        Form f = new Form();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView {Dock=DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=t};
        f.Controls.Add(dgv);
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i think I may be confusing the situation.  I can get the excel files into my application into a datatable.  How do I take that data table and create it in the SQL Database.  Your example is just reading the excel file into a local datatable in your application.  I can do that.  I need to push that to a temp table on sql server that does not exist.  How do I do that with sqlbulkcopy

Comment: @dk96m, just added an SqlBulkCopy sample. Note that it is a global temp table in SQ server.

Comment: But this is my problem, you know what the columns are.  Mine are changing.  You can create a table with those fields because you know the fields.  For me, the number of fields and what they are vary.

Comment: @dk96m, I DON"T need to know what columns available. As I explained, I am creating the temp table when I aldready have knowledge of Excel table. Getting schema I would simply build the string for create table at runtime.

Comment: In your example, you are doing mapping and creating a table with specific columns.  I think i understand what you are getting at.  I will try that again tomorrow.  I cant think anymore.  Thank you for the help.  I will let you know what happens and if I have more questions.

Comment: @dk96m, mapping is simple column 0 (first) to fieldX, 1 to fieldY and so on. That gives flexibility in choosing excel columns in any order and you don't need to get all of them. If you provide a sample excel file, I could specifically show code for that.

Comment: Ill see what I can do.  Let me get back to you.  Thank you again for the help